Slow syntax highlighting when working in C inside vscode
I am encountering an issue where vscode is very slow to correctly highlight syntax when coding in C. It tends to highlight variable names like functions and comments as functions too before it correctly changes color.
Syntax highlighting works just fine when working with other languages such as python.
Expected highlighting

Incorrect highlighting


This depends on the extensions you are using. Also on how many of them you have out there. Your code base size could also affect it.

@EugeneSh. the only C related extensions I have are C/C++, C/C++ Extension pack and C/C++ Themes all by microsoft. The example I gave literally only had 10ish lines of code and the issue seems to persist regardless of the file size.

@Whatevermeen If it's just 10 lines, would you post the exact code that caused the problem, your version of VSCode, and all extensions. Try turning off every other extension. Consider reporting this to VSCode as a bug.

@Schwern the code itself isn't an issue as the slow syntax highlighting happens regardless of the file. I'm using the version 1.92.2. Also I`m new to the site so how should I go about listing all the extenstions without cluttering the post itself?

Just disable all of irrelevant extensions, one by one, and see if it is changing the behavior.

I have disabling all the extenstions that are not needed one by one and nothing has changed. I will report it as a bug.

@Whatevermeen If you've disabled all unneeded extensions, add the extensions you had to leave on and their versions to your post (edit it into your post), along with a snippet of code that causes the problem (even if it'll do it with any code). You'll get much better answers with all information in the post, not in the comments.

Has your machine settled down before you start using VS code.  On some Windows machines, the virus checker and windows defender hammer the machine for the first few minutes, esp those with lots of files,  Sometimes slowness is because the temp files area is full.  Have you cleared down your AppData/Local/Temp (just delete all file in it, skip if they are still in use).
